# How to achieve Property Injection like IAbpSession?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to implement my own custom `IAbpSession`, but I do not know how to achieve the same property injection as `IAbpSession`.
My `AppServiceBase` is like below:

```
public abstract class EdwardAppServiceBase : ApplicationService
{
    public TenantManager TenantManager { get; set; }

    public UserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    protected EdwardActiveUnitOfWork EdwardActiveUnitOfWork => (EdwardActiveUnitOfWork)UnitOfWorkManager.Current;

    protected IEdwardSession EdwardSession { get; set; } 
    // protected IEdwardSession EdwardSession => AbpSession as IEdwardSession;

    protected SensingStoreCloudAppServiceBase()
    {
        // EdwardSession = NullEdwardSession.Instance;
        LocalizationSourceName = SensingStoreCloudConsts.LocalizationSourceName;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment `EdwardSession = NullEdwardSession.Instance;`, I always get `NullEdwardSession` instead of `IEdwardSession` implementation: `EdwardSession`.

I could only do `AbpSession as IEdwardSession`.

How does ABP inject `IAbpSession` and set its value in `ApplicationService`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABP uses Castle Windsor for dependency and [property injection](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/how-properties-are-injected.md):

> ## How properties are injected
>
> Property injection of dependencies is designed to be done during component activation when a component is created. The responsibility of determining which properties are used for injection is fulfilled by default through `PropertiesDependenciesModelInspector` - a `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` implementation which uses all the following criteria to determine if a property represents a dependency:
>
> - Has 'public' accessible setter
> - Is an instance property
> - If `ComponentModel.InspectionBehavior` is set to `PropertiesInspectionBehavior.DeclaredOnly`, is not inherited
> - Does not have parameters
> - Is not annotated with the `Castle.Core.DoNotWireAttribute` attribute

So make it `public`:

```cs
// protected IEdwardSession EdwardSession { get; set; }
public IEdwardSession EdwardSession { get; set; }
```